# "Fixed" position of currencies is being showed as "floating" when exporting Crystal Report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I set my currencies to be at fixed position (at left), but when I export the report, they are floating near digits. The example images are below:

[image: Design Mode]

[image: Exported Mode]

Comment: How do you, set the currencies ?? it is a image or number formatting...

Comment: Number formatting, fixed position. @Manoj

Answer (score 1):

In the Crystal Reports designer, right click on the field, then Font and finally check the "Strikeout".